# Layout of elements inside of HBox for JavaFX

Tags: java, css, alignment, javafx-8

I want to loop through each object of a list. For each entry I want to create a GUI object that looks like this:

- A checkbox on the left
- An image in the center
- (later) A label on the left

My problem is, that each label has a different length and it looks rather strange if not all pictures are on the same line (as seen vertically). Is there a possibility by either `java` or `css` to align the `ImageVew` in center of the `HBox`?
`imageView.setLayoutX(filterBox.getWidth()/2);` didn't do the trick unfortunatly. And no `-fx-align: right;` or `-fx-float: right;` seems to be existing.
I included what I have so far.

```
VBox filtersBox = new VBox();
HBox filterBox;
for(Filter filter : filters.getFilters()){
     if(!filter.isComplex()){
          filterBox = new HBox();
          filterBox.getStyleClass().add("filter");
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
          [image view stuff]
          final CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox(filter.getName().toString());
          filterBox.getChildren().addAll(cbox, imageView);
          filtersBox.getChildren().addAll(filterBox);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is impossible.

I see two ways you can achieve this layout, though:

1. Have all the checkboxes have the same (constant) preferred width. This way your image views should line up.
2. Use a [`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html), and add rows instead of `HBox`es